# How can I fortify a door using wood planks?

Tags: doors, security

I have an interior door which I want to beef up against a more-than-minimally determined adversary. I am on a budget, so I wish to make do with materials I already have on hand, with minimal/no further expenditure, namely a bunch of mattress support planks from a bedframe. I need the door to be usable and I want the reinforcement to be passive (ie. not rely on me having to be inside the room to lower a barricade bar, for example.)

The door is hollow, has no knob, and a deadbolt operated by a (turn)key. I wish to improve the door's resilience against brute-force only. The adversary will not pick the lock, nor will they have access to disproportionately powerful tools with which to attempt to breach the door (no breach shotguns or battering rams). However, there will be plenty of opportunity for them to have free rein to examine the door undisturbed, to either find a weakness or to make their way through one woodchip at a time, which there's nothing I can do about I suppose.

Given my threat model and constraints, how would I utilize the materials I have available to strengthen the door? Is there a particular/optimal pattern to nail the boards onto the door for maximum strength? Or is there a $5 silver bullet at Home Depot which will assuage all of my concerns and then some?

Comment: Most doors opening inside in a wood frame usually only need a few well place kicks to bust open.  Hollow doors might have 2x2s around the outside to hold the faces on.  Planks on inside and outside might need a few extra kicks to break the door(door will already be open by then).  You want a steel door in a steel frame opening out to make life difficult to get in.

Comment: Does the door swing into the space you want to protect, or the other way around?

Comment: What are the walls made of? Any *more-than-minimally determined adversary* with half a brain will go through a drywall/plasterboard wall in about 15 seconds if met with a door that doesn't smash open in 5 seconds.

Answer (score 5):

I'd start by hitting an architectural recycling supplier (admitted bias: Id start with the Habitat ReStores) and trying to get a solid door with the right dimensions. Much easier than trying to beef up a hollow door.

Then look at the hardware. The strike for a deadbolt is often not mounted as securely as it should be. Basic fix is to reinstall it with 3" screws that go all the way to the studs. Better fix (a bit of cost and a bit of work required) is to install a higher-security strike, which combines that improved anchoring with beefing up other features of that component.

You may also want to use 3" screws where the hinges are mounted to the door frame, while you're at it. Screws are cheap. To make installing them easier, and reduce the risk of wood splitting, it's a good idea to predrill with a bit narrower than the screw's threads (ideal is equal to or just a hair less than the diameter at the root of the threads; if in doubt, go for narrower).

If you're concerned about brute force attacks, you also want to make sure that lockset is Grade 2 or Grade 1, which are physically stronger that the Grade 3 hardware most builders (and economy-minded homeowners) install.

And of course if you think a force attack is likely, you need to think about securing the rest of the enclosure. Anyone who would kick in a door will be just as happy going through a window. Or a wall, if they can.

On the other hand, remember that in most situations you don't need bank-vault security. You just need to be visibly secure enough that the crook decides it's easier and safer to attack someone else.

Comment: And if you have spare wood, reinforce the door frame around the striker plate, and reinforce the edge of the door where the lock is mounted.

Comment: Might even get lucky and find a steel door at ReStore, if that suits the OP's security needs.

Comment: May be harder to fit a steel door to an existing opening if things have shifted and the opening is not exactly a standard size, but yes. (When I installed a steel door I special ordered it to the needed size, and planned on reworking the doorframe anyway.) One drawback of steel doors is that older ones, at least, are poorly insulated.